# Generics and parallel class hierarchies

Tags: generics

I'm having some problems with using generics in combination with parallel class hierarchies. I have coded myself into this mess several times already.

Let's say I have the following class hierarchies:
TableColumn -> subclasses SqlTableColumn, OracleTableColumn
Table -> subclasses SqlTable, OracleTable
Database -> subsclasses SqlDatabase, OracleDatabase

I use generics on the base types, which gives:

```
Table<TableColumn>
Database<Table<TableColumn>>

SqlTable<SqlTableColumn>
SqlDatabase<SqlTable<SqlTableColumn>>

OracleTable<OracleTableColumn>
OracleDatabase<OracleTable<OracleTableColumn>>
```

I have a feeling this is not a good use of generics. What would be a better design?

Comment: Which programming language (I guess Java or C#)?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring any theoretical stuff behind generics on when to use them, this seems more natural to me (in C#):

```
class Database<T, C>
    where T : Table<C>
    where C : TableColumn { }
class Table<C>
    where C : TableColumn { }
class TableColumn { }

//sql
class SqlDatabase : Database<SqlTable, SqlColumn> { }
class SqlTable : Table<SqlColumn> { }
class SqlColumn : TableColumn { }

//oracle
class OracleDatabase : Database<OracleTable, OracleColumn> { }
class OracleTable : Table<OracleColumn> { }
class OracleColumn : TableColumn { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics (as in Java or C#) is really intended to support **parameterized types**. In this case, the types you are passing (TableColumn, SqlTableColumn) are not really intended to be type parameters.

I would implement this set of types as parallel object hierarchies, not parameterized types. For example:

```
OracleTable extends Table
SqlTable extends Table

OracleDatabase extends Database
SqlDatabase extends Database

OracleTableColumn extends TableColumn
SqlTableColumn extends TableColumn
```

The public methods on all these types should refer only to the base classes, as is done in JDBC, for example.